# Admob Native Ads in RecyclerView Not Working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I am trying to use Native Ads in My RecyclerView but there is one error coming in App and it Crashes. Please Check Below Code:

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ats.sarkarijobs, PID: 32337
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
        at com.ats.sarkarijobs.NativeAdView.<init>(NativeAdView.java:18)
        at com.ats.sarkarijobs.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:56)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
```

...
**NativeAdView Holder**

```
public class NativeAdView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private UnifiedNativeAdView adView;
     UnifiedNativeAdView getAdView() {
        return adView;
    }
    public NativeAdView(View view){
        super(view);
        adView = view.findViewById(R.id.ad_media);
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById((R.id.ad_call)));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_icon));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
    }
}
```

**onCreateViewHolder Function**

```
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case native_ad_view:
                View unifiedNativeAd = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_native_ad_view, parent, false);
                return new NativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd);
            case item_view:
                default:
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);
                    return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view) ;
        }
    }
```

Native Ads in My RecyclerView but there is one error coming in App and it Crashes. Please Check above Code:

Comment: please attach your XML.

Comment: Error should be in your xml layout. it's casting error. you are trying to cast com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView in to om.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView.  Make sure you are using same thing both the side.

Comment: I have used same code as of google codelab: [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#5) Still Not Working